# Using IsEmpty and Merging empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm writing code that searches through a very large excel sheet with a lot of duplicates, I can easily sort the duplicates together as they all have 1 matching column, and ID column. The thing that I am stuck on is why IsEmpty isn't working for looking at the current cell and seeing if it's empty and if the next cell (the duplicate) has data. Then the cell with data would merge over into the cell that's empty.

I've tried using Range as the argument as well as cells to no avail.

```
Private Sub CountDuplicates()
Dim i As Integer

'The cell it will use to search
Dim idCheck As Range

'The cell it will use to compare text
Dim currentCell As Range

'This will be used to format the "Changes" column
Dim rowNumberValue As Integer, columnNumberValue As Integer, rowBelow As Integer
placement = 0
colNum = 3

rowNumberValue = ActiveCell.Row
columnNumberValue = ActiveCell.Column
rowBelow = ActiveCell.Row + 1

'Searches by ID column
For Each idCheck In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B1000")

   'This checks to find duplicate ID rows
   If idCheck.Value = idCheck.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then

         'Goes from each column starting from the ID column (H = 7th letter in alphabet and H is the last column)
         For colNum = 3 To 7

            'Checks to see if the cell has no value but the duplicate does
            If IsEmpty(Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum))) = True And IsEmpty(Range(Cells(rowNumberValue + 1, colNum))) = False Then
               Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum), Cells(rowBelow, colNum)).Merge
```

So ideally, if a row has one cell missing data, but the other row has it, then merge/copy the data into the cell with missing data.

Comment: You want the `And` operator instead of `&`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, still getting the same error though. "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: What's actually *in* the cells? `IsEmpty` isn't not working. Something else is wrong :)

Comment: @DavidZemens The cells vary from column, between text and numeric values, most of them are text.

Comment: Note also that `Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum)...` is **not** qualified to a particular worksheet, so it refers to whatever worksheet is *active* at runtime.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `If` statement and then evaluate `Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum)).Value` in the Immediate pane of the VBE. Might also check `Len(Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum)).Value)` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace tests like:

```
IsEmpty(Range(Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum))) = True
```

with:

```
Cells(rowNumberValue, colNum) = ""
```

Comment: @Frost10000 it's best practice to qualify which Worksheet the `Cells` or `Range` are on. In your case it looks like that's `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. That's what a previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567952/using-isempty-and-merging-empty-cells#comment99715277_56567952) was getting at.

Comment: @BigBen  **You are correct !**  The code will profit by using ***With*** in the proper place.